# two-dimension vector custom predicate greater function

Tags: c++, sorting, predicate

I have a two-dimension vector like below.

```
vector<vector<int>> vec = {{2,5}, {3, 4}, {0,1}, {1,2}}
```

I want to sort this array based on the second element of each vec[i].
So the end result should be

```
{{2,5},{3,4},{1,2}, {0,1}}
```

I want to use something like

```
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), secondGreater);

bool secondGreater(vector<int> a, vector<int> b){
  return a[1]>b[1];
}
```

My thinking is: each element of vec is a one-dimension vector, so i provide one function to compare two one-dimension vector. But somehow it doesn't work. Any hint?

Thanks.

//-------------------------------------------------

The code is like below, and the error message is

**Line 6: Char 46: error: reference to non-static member function must be called
sort(boxTypes.begin(), boxTypes.end(), secondGreater);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.**

```
class Solution {
public:
    int maximumUnits(vector<vector<int>>& boxTypes, int truckSize) {
      int cnt=0;
      
      sort(boxTypes.begin(), boxTypes.end(), secondGreater);
      
      for(auto i=0;i<boxTypes.size();i++){
        if(truckSize > boxTypes[i][0]){
          cnt+= boxTypes[i][0] * boxTypes[i][1];
          truckSize -= boxTypes[i][0];
        }
        else if(truckSize>0 && truckSize < boxTypes[i][0]){
          cnt+= boxTypes[i][1] * truckSize;
          break;
        }
        else break;
      }
      return cnt;
      
    }
    
    bool secondGreater(vector<int> boxA, vector<int> boxB){
      return boxA[1] > boxB[1];
    }
};
```

Comment: Please specify exactly what "doesn't work" means. Please also create a [mre] that allows anyone to quickly reproduce the error in their own environment and fix it.

Comment: What is the issue that are you facing, For me it is working

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce with a basic test: https://godbolt.org/z/P3c6ozTjT Can you explain what exactly you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: added the original code.

Comment: The issue is that `secondGreater` is a member function so you can't just pass it as an argument like that. Make it static or keep it outside `Solution`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`secondGreater` is a member function. But you are trying to call it as if it were a free function with no associated object.

Since it accesses no member variables, it doesn't need to be a member function, move it outside the class:

```
bool secondGreater(vector<int> boxA, vector<int> boxB){
   return boxA[1] > boxB[1];
}

class Solution
```

If you for some reason needed it to be in the class, you could make it static:

```
static bool secondGreater( ...
```

If you need it for some reason to be a non-static member function, aka you need state from the class in the future, then you could  `bind` `this` to it:

```
sort(boxTypes.begin(), boxTypes.end(), std::bind(secondGreater, this, _1, _2)); 
// This code is only psuedo code.
```

Or since it is so simple, just replace the whole thing with a lambda:

```
sort(boxTypes.begin(), boxTypes.end(), [](vector<int> boxA, vector<int> boxB){
   return boxA[1] > boxB[1];
});
```

Comment: thanks for the detail. Need to study a bit more on static member function. Went through too quickly when going through textbook

Comment: @WriteBackCMO There is a good chance you don't actually need this to be a static member function. From the looks of it, you only care about this in your class. If you implement your class in a cpp file, add an anonymous namespace to that file and put the function in it. Then no one needs to know that it is even in the class at all.

Comment: `[](vector<int> boxA, vector<int> boxB)` we should not use a copy here, it's a waste!

Answer (score 1):

Make it static, then it should work:

```
static bool secondGreater(vector<int> boxA, vector<int> boxB) {
      return boxA[1] > boxB[1];
}
```

If a non-static function is needed, this can be achieved via

```
sort(boxTypes.begin(), boxTypes.end(), std::bind(&Solution::secondGreater, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
```

Comment: yes, it works. can you provide some brief explanation?

Comment: The problem is that when it is non-static, like you first tried, it is relative to an instance of your class. Non-static methods are implicitly passed the `this` pointer as a first parameter so they know which instance they're being invoked on. If you call `sort` the way you did, you're not telling the program what the `this` pointer is to pass to the method. Since you're not accessing any members in `secondGreater`, a `static` method is enough. If you really need a non-static method, that can be achieved too using `std::bind`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix could be. Just add `static` before the comparator function.

```
static bool secondGreater(vector<int> boxA, vector<int> boxB){
  return boxA[1] > boxB[1];
}
```